# C# Enums returning wrong int value

Tags: c#

```
public enum Question
{
    A= 02,
    B= 13,
    C= 04,
    D= 15,
    E= 06,
}
```

but when i use

```
int something = (int)Question.A;
```

i get 2 instead of 02. How can i get 02?

Comment: Oh well if you do a 2 == 02 it will equal. 2 and 02, int-wise, are the same.

Comment: you simply can't: it's an integer, so the correct result is 2!! 02 is a string and you can't use it as result for enums

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integers are not strings. It sounds like you want to format a string with at least two digits, which you can do with:

```
string text = value.ToString("00"); // For example; there are other ways
```

It's important to distinguish between the *text* representation of a value, and the information which is *actually stored* in a value.

For example, consider:

```
int base10 = 255;
int base16 = 0xff;
```

Here both variables have the same value. They were initialized using different forms of numeric literal, but they're the same value. Both could be *formatted* in decimal, hex, binary, whatever you want - but the values themselves are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

`02` is a string representation of `2` with a precending zero. If you need to output this value somewhere try to use custom string format:

```
String.Format("{0:00}", (int)Question.A)

or

((int)Question.A).ToString("00")
```

For more details regarding this format string see on MSDN ["The "0" Custom Specifier"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0)

Comment: @senzacionale : sorry, I've updated the answer. Forgot to add first parameter placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Integers are numbers - just like with money, $1 equals $1.00 and $000001. If you want to *display* a number in a certain way, you can use:

```
string somethingReadyForDisplay = something.ToString("D2");
```

Which converts the number into a string containing "02".

Answer (score 1):

2 is exactly the same as 02, and 002 and 0002 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post : [Enum With String Values In C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx) by this you can satisfy the needs easily realated to string

You can also try this option

```
 public enum Test : int {
        [StringValue("02")]
        Foo = 1,
        [StringValue("14")]
        Something = 2       
 }
```

new custom attribute class, the source is below:

```
/// <summary>
/// This attribute is used to represent a string value
/// for a value in an enum.
/// </summary>
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute {

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the stringvalue for a value in an enum.
    /// </summary>
    public string StringValue { get; protected set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used to init a StringValue Attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public StringValueAttribute(string value) {
        this.StringValue = value;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

created a new Extension Method which I will use to get the string value for an enums value:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Will get the string value for a given enums value, this will
    /// only work if you assign the StringValue attribute to
    /// the items in your enum.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value) {
        // Get the type
        Type type = value.GetType();

        // Get fieldinfo for this type
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

        // Get the stringvalue attributes
        StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

        // Return the first if there was a match.
        return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].StringValue : null;
    }
```

finally read value by

```
Test t = Test.Foo;
string val = t.GetStringValue();

- or even -

string val = Test.Foo.GetStringValue();
```

Comment: thx Rana. I found original link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stringenum.aspx

Answer (score 0):

02( the index ) stored as integer so you can't get it as 02 !!